# How to set Azure DevOps pipeline authentication so that it doesn't require intervention

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have dozens of Azure DevOps pipelines that deploy stuff to Azure using service principals in customers' tenants. The app registrations have a client secret that is used to authenticate the pipeline.

Until now, we've been able to set the expiration time to "never" (like 200 years), but it seems that it's no longer possible. Now the maximum is only 2 years.

[image: client secret dialog]

I could not find any documentation or change logs about this change.

I understand that "never" expiring client secrets are not the most secure, but renewing them for dozens of pipelines is a huge additional maintenance job.

Is there a way to set the pipelines in a way that doesn't require intervention after the initial setup?

Answer (score 0):

As of this time, however, setting the expiration time to more than 2 years is not supported.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any documentation about this change? Any changedocs or recommended practises after the change? Imagine having 200 build pipelines for 100 customers and having to remember when their client secrets expire. And then to update them manually for each project.